# NativeScript and mongodb integration

Tags: mongodb, nativescript

I have created a simple nativescript application which works fine without interacting with any database. I have reached a point where I need to get/put data from MongoDB.

So I have built a MongoDB framework with the help of https://mlab.com/ which works great as expected using nodeJS modules.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
 , assert = require('assert');

var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
 , assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://user:password@ds145329.mlab.com:12345/dbname';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  // CRUD Operation goes here...
});
```

Now I need to integrate the MongoDB framework with the nativescript application that I created.

The question is if I will be able to ***require*** the nodeJS libraries inside NativeScript? If yes, how?

Thank you for helping,

Seyed Ismail MAC.

Answer (score 1):

> The question is if I will be able to require the nodeJS libraries
>   inside NativeScript? If yes, how?

No, your node server is the API you contact. It handles all mongodb communication then sends database query data back to nativescript.

In Nativescript, you merely do REST requests(like get or put) to the backend server/API.

So Think of it like a website:

Nativescript is your front end(angular, react, html, css).

NodeJS and mongodb are your backend.

Communication is same between the front and backend as a website.

EDIT: You have this code twice for some reason. I would remove one:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
 , assert = require('assert');
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks. 
How do I do REST requests to the backend from NativeScript and pass data with it, to insert or read entries from it?

Comment: https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/http

http requests like any other angular 2 application